# Beautifulsoup4 - getting multiple non-uniquely tagged text strings and storing in a list

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

EDIT: I would also like helping grabbing the "Classes of business" values listed for each company, but using the answer below, the `strong.text.strip() == 'Classes of business'` does not appear to ever be `True` based on my code.

I'm fairly experienced with beautifulsoup and python but for whatever reason can't seem to property grab this data. Below is the HTML block I'm working in:

```
<div class="marketing-directories-results">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="contact-details">
                <h2>
                    A I I Insurance Brokerage of Massachusetts Inc
                </h2>
                <br/>
                <address>
                    183 Davis St
                    <br/>
                    East Douglas
                    <br/>
                    Massachusetts
                    <br/>
                    U S A
                    <br/>
                    MA 01516-113
                </address>
                <p>
                    <a href="http://www.agencyint.com">
                        www.agencyint.com
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <span data-toggle=".info-cov-0">
                Additional trading information
                <i class="icon plus">
                </i>
            </span>
            <ul class="result-info info-cov-0 cc">
                <li>
                    <strong>
                        Accepts Business From:
                    </strong>
                    <ul class="cc">
                        <li>
                            U.S.A
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>
                        Classes of business
                    </strong>
                    <ul class="cc">
                        <li>
                            Engineering
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            NM General Liability (US direct)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Property D&amp;F (US binder)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Terrorism
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>
                        Disclaimer:
                    </strong>
                    <p>
                        Please note that while coverholders may have been approved by Lloyd's to accept business from the regions shown:
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        it is the responsibility of the parties, including the coverholder and any Lloyd's managing agent appointing them to ensure that the coverholder complies with all local regulatory and legal requirements; and
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        the coverholder may not provide cover for all classes they are approved to underwrite in all territories where they have approval.
                    </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="contact-details">
                <h2>
                    ABCO Insurance Underwriters Inc
                </h2>
                <br/>
                <address>
                    ABCO Building, 350 Sevilla Avenue, Suite 201
                    <br/>
                    Coral Gables
                    <br/>
                    Florida
                    <br/>
                    U S A
                    <br/>
                    33134
                </address>
                <p>
                    <a href="http://www.abcoins.com">
                        www.abcoins.com
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <span data-toggle=".info-cov-1">
                Additional trading information
                <i class="icon plus">
                </i>
            </span>
            <ul class="result-info info-cov-1 cc">
                <li>
                    <strong>
                        Accepts Business From:
                    </strong>
                    <ul class="cc">
                        <li>
                            U.S.A
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>
                        Classes of business
                    </strong>
                    <ul class="cc">
                        <li>
                            Property D&amp;F (US binder)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Terrorism
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>
                        Disclaimer:
                    </strong>
                    <p>
                        Please note that while coverholders may have been approved by Lloyd's to accept business from the regions shown:
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        it is the responsibility of the parties, including the coverholder and any Lloyd's managing agent appointing them to ensure that the coverholder complies with all local regulatory and legal requirements; and
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        the coverholder may not provide cover for all classes they are approved to underwrite in all territories where they have approval.
                    </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The page shown has 10 records (I have only included the HTML for the first two so I can be helped to iterate through each company), each corresponding to a company along with more information about them such as their address, website url, and things like "Accepts business from: U.S.A."

I've been able to grab the names, addresses, and website urls, but I'm having trouble getting the "U.S.A." under "Accepts business from" (if they have it) for each company and storing it in the correct position in a list.

I can get to the first U.S.A with:

```
other_info = comp_info_area.find_all('li')

other_info_next = other_info[0].find('ul')
other_info_next_next = other_info_next.find_all('li')
other_info_next_next_next = other_info_next_next[0].find('ul', class_='cc')
other_info_next_next_next_next = other_info_next_next_next.find('li')
print(other_info_next_next_next_next.text)
```

Where `comp_info_area` is the Beautifulsoup object storing the HTML above. This returns: `U.S.A`

How can I grab the rest of those things? I can't figure out how to navigate the tree to get there. Any help is very much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Below is an example of a company that doesn't have that information:

```
<li>
    <div class="contact-details">
        <h2>
            Acadian Managers, LLC
        </h2>
        <br/>
        <address>
            8550 United Plaza Boulevard
            <br/>
            Suite 702
            <br/>
            Baton Rouge
            <br/>
            Louisiana
            <br/>
            U.S.A
            <br/>
            70809
        </address>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.acadianmanagers.com">
                www.acadianmanagers.com
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you give an example where the `Accepts business from` is not available? Since you said `(if they have it)`, there must be some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary for each company and then append it to the list.

```
# Get the <ul> tag which contains all the companies.
results = soup.find('div', class_='marketing-directories-results').ul

companies_info = []

# Iterate over the companies (all <li> tags that are direct children of results,
# can be found by setting 'recursive=False').
for company in results.find_all('li', recursive=False):
    company_info = {}
    company_info['Name'] = company.find('h2').text.strip()
    company_info['Address'] = company.find('address').get_text(', ', strip=True)
    company_info['Website'] = company.find('a', href=True)['href']

    try:
        li = company.find('ul', class_='result-info').find('li')
        if li.strong.text.strip() == 'Accepts Business From:':
            company_info['Accepts Business From'] = li.find('li').text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        # If this error is caught, it means this info is not available.
        # You can use the below line to set it to 'None', or simply use 'pass' to do nothing.
        company_info['Accepts Business From'] = None

    companies_info.append(company_info)

print(companies_info)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        'Name': 'A I I Insurance Brokerage of Massachusetts Inc', 
        'Address': '183 Davis St, East Douglas, Massachusetts, U S A, MA 01516-113', 
        'Website': 'http://www.agencyint.com', 
        'Accepts Business From': 'U.S.A'
    }, 
    {
        'Name': 'ABCO Insurance Underwriters Inc', 
        'Address': 'ABCO Building, 350 Sevilla Avenue, Suite 201, Coral Gables, Florida, U S A, 33134', 
        'Website': 'http://www.abcoins.com', 
        'Accepts Business From': 'U.S.A'
    }, 
    {
        'Name': 'Acadian Managers, LLC', 
        'Address': '8550 United Plaza Boulevard, Suite 702, Baton Rouge, Louisiana, U.S.A, 70809', 
        'Website': 'http://www.acadianmanagers.com', 
        'Accepts Business From': None
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! I've added an example of a company that doesn't have that info (in my original post), if you wouldn't mind including that in your example. No problem if not, you've already been very helpful.

Comment: If the company doesn't have that info, do want `'Accepts Business From': None` or do you simply don't want that line at all?

Comment: @RichardGolz, check the edit. I've added the new case and changed the code a bit (used try-except).

Comment: Could you add a bit of code that grabs the "Classes of business" information? In the first part of the HTML it would be the "Engineering" "General Liability" "Property" and "Terrorism" values. I have tried doing `if li.strong.text.strip() == 'Classes of business':` but for some reason it does not appear to be detecting it

Comment: here is a link to the updated question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49018025/beautifulsoup4-identifying-info-by-strong-tag-value-only-works-for-some-values

Comment: @RichardGolz, sorry couldn't answer that question here as it was a bit out of scope for this quesiton. I've posted a solution for your second question.