# Beautifulsoup4 - Identifying info by strong tag value only works for some values of the tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working with the following 'block' of HTML:

```
<div class="marketing-directories-results">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="contact-details">
                <h2>
                    A I I Insurance Brokerage of Massachusetts Inc
                </h2>
                <br/>
                <address>
                    183 Davis St
                    <br/>
                    East Douglas
                    <br/>
                    Massachusetts
                    <br/>
                    U S A
                    <br/>
                    MA 01516-113
                </address>
                <p>
                    <a href="http://www.agencyint.com">
                        www.agencyint.com
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <span data-toggle=".info-cov-0">
                Additional trading information
                <i class="icon plus">
                </i>
            </span>
            <ul class="result-info info-cov-0 cc">
                <li>
                    <strong>
                        Accepts Business From:
                    </strong>
                    <ul class="cc">
                        <li>
                            U.S.A
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>
                        Classes of business
                    </strong>
                    <ul class="cc">
                        <li>
                            Engineering
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            NM General Liability (US direct)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Property D&amp;F (US binder)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Terrorism
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>
                        Disclaimer:
                    </strong>
                    <p>
                        Please note that while coverholders may have been approved by Lloyd's to accept business from the regions shown:
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        it is the responsibility of the parties, including the coverholder and any Lloyd's managing agent appointing them to ensure that the coverholder complies with all local regulatory and legal requirements; and
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        the coverholder may not provide cover for all classes they are approved to underwrite in all territories where they have approval.
                    </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="contact-details">
                <h2>
                    ABCO Insurance Underwriters Inc
                </h2>
                <br/>
                <address>
                    ABCO Building, 350 Sevilla Avenue, Suite 201
                    <br/>
                    Coral Gables
                    <br/>
                    Florida
                    <br/>
                    U S A
                    <br/>
                    33134
                </address>
                <p>
                    <a href="http://www.abcoins.com">
                        www.abcoins.com
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <span data-toggle=".info-cov-1">
                Additional trading information
                <i class="icon plus">
                </i>
            </span>
            <ul class="result-info info-cov-1 cc">
                <li>
                    <strong>
                        Accepts Business From:
                    </strong>
                    <ul class="cc">
                        <li>
                            U.S.A
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>
                        Classes of business
                    </strong>
                    <ul class="cc">
                        <li>
                            Property D&amp;F (US binder)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Terrorism
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>
                        Disclaimer:
                    </strong>
                    <p>
                        Please note that while coverholders may have been approved by Lloyd's to accept business from the regions shown:
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        it is the responsibility of the parties, including the coverholder and any Lloyd's managing agent appointing them to ensure that the coverholder complies with all local regulatory and legal requirements; and
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        the coverholder may not provide cover for all classes they are approved to underwrite in all territories where they have approval.
                    </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am grabbing multiple data points from this HTML. The ones giving me trouble are the "Accepts Business From:" and "Classes of business" values. I can get the "Accepts Business From:" value regardless of which order it appears in via:

```
try:
    li_area = company.find('ul', class_='result-info info-cov-' + 
                                  str(company_counter) + ' cc')
    li_stuff = li_area.find_all('li')
    for li in li_stuff:
        if li.strong.text.strip() == 'Accepts Business From:':
            business_final = li.find('li').text.strip()
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Note: The "company" variable is the beautifulsoup object containing the html I have pasted above.

Note: the class name changes for each record on the page - I have only included one record in the HTML example in order to keep some semblance of brevity.

When I attempt the same block of code, this time replacing the li.strong.text.strip() == `'Accepts Business From:'` with `'Classes of business'` but the code does not appear to detect that strong tag, just the 'Accepts Business From:'. Is my for loop incorrect, and not actually iterating through each of the `<li>` tags that contain these different strong labels? Is it that the real value of that strong tag is something different than 'Classes of business?' (I did copy that value directly from the site's html).

Any help you can provide in getting to that is much appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting text for `'Accepts Business From:'` and not for `'Classes of business'` is that you're using the `try-except` in the wrong place.

In the second iteration of the `for li in li_stuff:` loop, `li` becomes `<li>U.S.A</li>`, which will throw and `AttributeError` for calling `li.strong` on it since there's not `<strong>` tag present. And, according to your current `try-except`, the error is caught outsite the `for` loop and is `pass`ed. So, the loop won't reach its third iteration in which it should be getting the text for 'Classes of business'.

To continue to loop even after the error is caught, use this:

```
for li in li_stuff:
    try:
        if li.strong.text.strip() == 'Accepts Business From:':
            business_final = li.find('li').text.strip()
            print('Accepts Business From:', business_final)
        if li.strong.text.strip() == 'Classes of business':
            business_final = li.find('li').text.strip()
            print('Classes of business:', business_final)
    except AttributeError:
        pass  # or you can use 'continue' too.
```

Output:

```
Accepts Business From: U.S.A
Classes of business: Engineering
```

But, as there are many values present for the 'Classes of business', you can change your code to this to get them all:

```
if li.strong.text.strip() == 'Classes of business':
    business_final = ', '.join([x.text.strip() for x in li.find_all('li')])
    print('Classes of business:', business_final)
```

Output:

```
Accepts Business From: U.S.A
Classes of business: Engineering, NM General Liability (US direct), Property D&F (US binder), Terrorism
```

Comment: Keyur, you're the best. Thanks so much. Worked for me and the explanation was very helpful